# Hadoop Implement a status callback

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am looking for a clean way to implement a java event system that hooks into Hadoop v2. I know there is a notification url and I have used that in the past. What I want to do is to hook into the JobStatus and have events posted to a queue service for propagating events to client. I tried extending job and assigning the status using reflection to my custom JobStatus class but this is not working. I have also cursory looked into Yarn's event system to add a hook that will allow me to listen for yarn events and propagate those. I really need an expert opinion on how to accomplish this kind of task. I want to get log messages, status change events in real time over to a web client.

Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Comment: I do also have the same question.

Comment: I had to roll my own. I was able to get it working.I don't have the source code anymore but I remember having to modify a couple of files in the core hadoop to get it to work. I think the majority of changes was in MRMaster.java.